# How to update first three rows with different values in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to update the first three results with different values (from 1 to 3) :

Query to get the first 3 results :

```
$top3 = DB::table('quests')
                    ->orderby('score', 'desc') 
                    ->take(3)
                    ->pluck('id');
```

Query to update a column with a rank of 1 to 3 :

```
DB::table('quests')->whereIn('id', $top3)
                     ->first()->update(['rank', 1])
                     ->second()->update(['rank', 2])
                     ->third()->update(['rank', 3]);
              //of course the above updates are from my imagination :)
              //just trying to describe what I'm trying to do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query is redundant; there is no reason to query for `ids` to just query the table again. Do it all in one query/loop:

```
$top3 = Quest::orderBy("score", "DESC")->take(3)->get();
foreach($top3 AS $index => $quest){
  $quest->rank = $index+1;
  $quest->save();
}
```

Note: This assumes you have a `Quest` model; will still work with `DB::table()`, but if you're using Laravel, use models.

The above will fetch the 3 records in a single query, properly handling ordering and limiting, then looping and assigning a rank (0-based `$index`, incremented on each loop, adding 1 to handle)